# Show button when max characters written

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-animation

I have an `edittext` that has a limit of 150 characters, when all the characters have been written a button appears which brings the user to the next activity, i have done it like this:

```
EditText yourEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextNew);

     yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {}

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(s.length() >= 150){

                    bubble = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
                    bubble.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(NewTextActivity.this, R.anim.push_left_in);
                    bubble.startAnimation(anim);

                    counter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewCount);
                    counter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Animation anim2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(NewTextActivity.this, R.anim.fade_out);
                    counter.startAnimation(anim2);


              }}
            }
        );
```

I have set the visibility to the button to gone in the `xml`, and then visible when 150 characters have been written, and that works good, but what i want to create now is that when a character is removed, the button should be hidden again, and only be visible when there is 150 characters in the `edittext`.

I have tried fixing it like this:

```
@Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(s.length() <= 149){
```

But this made the button "`flash`" every time a character was written.

Any tips on how i could make the button disabled and then only show when there is 150 characters, and then be disabled again when a character is removed?

Comment: Change it to `s.length() == 150`

Comment: Add an `else {}` after the if length statement which reverts the button to hidden?

Answer (score 1):

check for character length `greater than and equal to 150` and make it `visible` else `hide` it.

```
 if(s.length() >= 150){
        bubble.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }
 else{
        bubble.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 }
```